# Format sensor data as it comes into IBM Watson

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, cloudant, node-red

I am still new to IBM Watson. Is there any way that i can format the sensor data that comes into IBM Watson? The issue that i am facing right now is that the timestamp bunch the date and the time together and it poses problems when i try to create certain data visualizations in any data analytics and visualization software. I will make things easier for me splitting the date and time from the timestamp. I am aware that the data is in json format.

In addition, I am using node-red, do let me know if the formatting of data should be done at node red.

Here is my sample sensor data :

```
{
   "_id": "04691370-387e-11e8-8cd5-8b3f61628d0d",
   "_rev": "1-a4328ecd41d03b8e4ac86de06baf03d2",
   "deviceType": "RaspberryPi",
   "deviceId": "9074bd",
   "eventType": "event",
   "format": "json",
   "timestamp": "2018-04-05T11:04:12.583+08:00",
   "data": {
     "d": {
       "temperature": 19.5,
       "humidity": 44,
       "heatIndex": 18.65
     }
   }
 }
```

Things that I am using:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- Raspbian for Robots (Dexter Industries)
- GrovePi+
- GrovePi DHT 11, Light sensor , Sound sensor , UV sensor
- Node Red with all the grovepi+ nodes including nodes for IBM Watson
- IBM Watson , IBM Waston Iot
- Cloudant NoSQL DB
- CData ODBC Driver for Cloudant
- Microsoft Power Bi (subject to change , depends on which software is easier to Adopt)

Answer (score 1):

This is just JSON data, there is nothing to stop you adding 2 new fields to the object (e.g `date` and `time`).

It's probably simplest to do this in Node-RED with a function node with something like the following:

```
var timestamp = msg.payload.timestamp;

msg.payload.date = timestamp.substring(0,timestamp.indexOf('T'));
msg.payload.time = timestamp.substring(timestamp.indexOf('T') + 1);
return msg;
```

Comment: There is an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" and I also realized that the payload object for the sensor data is as follows:  `{ temperature: 20.5, humidity: 42, heatIndex: 19.7 }`

Comment: And to add on, the sensor data that i provided is from IBM Watson Iot, not node red (my apologies for not saying it earlier)